# How to set up Firefox on Linux to select all the current URL string on click in the location bar?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, url, address-bar

How to get the same behavior of the URL address bar on Linux as on Firefox for Windows. I mean the whole URL gets selected by first click and unselected with cursor position where second click was made. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: URL is selected whole with double click. You may use Ctrl+L

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can do that**. Write in the address bar `about:config` and press enter. Accept the warning. Then in the search bar you will now see above your settings type `click` - that will open click related settings. Choose `browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll` and set it's value to `true`. From now the new tabs windows you open will show this behaviour you want.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, that's exactly the setting I was hoping for!